# Does Lua support Decorators?

Tags: python, programming-languages, syntax, lua, decorator

I come from a Python background and really like the power of Python Decorators.

Does Lua support Decorators?

I've read the following link but it's unclear to me:  http://lua-users.org/wiki/DecoratorsAndDocstrings

**UPDATE**

Would you also mind given an example how how to implement it in Lua if it's possible.

Comment: Lua can implement wrappers around functions just as well as Python can; it just doesn't have a special syntax for it, since Lua aims to have a very basic core syntax (to a fault, as it lacks such basic things as `continue` and `+=`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "decorators" documented at the page you quote (and used for example in [this one](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaTypeChecking) to add type-checking) have little to do with Python's oddly-named "decorator syntax" for a specific way to apply a higher-order function (HOF) -- rather, the decorators described and used in Lua's wiki are a Lua idiom to support an application of the [Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to Lua functions (by holding "extra attributes" -- such as docstrings, typechecking functions, etc -- in separate global tables).

Lua does support HOFs (I'm not sure if you can re-bind a function name to the result of applying a HOF to the function, but you *can* easily, as the wiki pages show, use an anonymous "original function" and only bind a name to the HOF's result with that anon function as the arg).

Python's "decorator syntax" syntax sugar is nice (and, to my surprise, seems to have increased the use of HOFs by most Pythonistas by an order of magnitude!-), but there's nothing intrinsic or essential about them that you can't do in Lua (and Lua's anonymous functions run circle around Python's goofy, limited `lambda` anyway -- just like in Javascript, they have essentially the same power, and pretty much the same syntax, as a "normal" named function!-).

Comment: would you mind then giving an example on how to implement a HOF in Lua. Thanks

Comment: @user, the wiki page you quoted is full of such examples -- functions taking function arguments and/or returning function results (that's what a higher-order function, aka HOF, **is**, by definition;-).  I don't think there would be any added value in me copying and pasting any of those examples or variations thereon!

Comment: Functions in Lua are first class values. They don't actually have names at all. You "bind" a name to a function by storing it in a variable of that name. So to rebind an existing function, you just replace its value, being careful to retain access to the old value if needed, of course.